# "Could Not Connect To site" error when Installing IOS 7.1 app

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ssl, ios7

Trying to install app onto IOS 7.1. I have gotten SSL cert and it is all set up. But now instead of getting the cert error I get "Can not connect to site" error.

PHP code:

```
if ($detect->isiOS()) {
        header("Location: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.SITE.com/app/APP.plist");
    }
```

Plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.SITE.com/app/APP.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.leprinofoods.APP</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>APP</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is the certificate an official cert or an self signed?

Comment: Official, got it from godaddy.

Comment: Can you download the plist file?